# Visual Studio Express in Ubuntu12.10

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2012, ubuntu-12.10

Is it possible to install **Visual Studio Express** in Ubuntu???

I've Visual Studio In my Windows7 OS but I want to install it in *Ubuntu*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to install MICROSOFT visual studio on linux, no there's no way to do that use aptana

You could try looking into wine and emulation but don't expect it to work 100%

Comment: Not a problem mate, Trust me you'll love aptana, just google aptana for ubuntu for the full tutorial

Comment: Yeah, if you like Eclipse, you'll love aptana. If you hate the ever decreasing speed of Visual Studio, you'll love CodeBlocks. It's native (no java) and it screams along. I'm running it in win7, linux mint and Raspian - even on the 700mhz *battery powered* PI, it compiles and runs a hello-world program oodles faster than a quad-core P4 or an i3 will run Eclipse, VS or aptana. It can open older VS project files, too.

Comment: Agree with you there enhzflep, all though code blocks is more for serious programming while aptana is more or less for web dev.

Comment: Aptana is great, but I am currently using Visual Studio, since my Netconnect+ is not compatible with Ubintu12.10. anyone knows how to do it please suggest.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/232670/how-to-run-use-internet-with-reliance-netconnect-in-ubuntu-12-10desktop-32bit

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible, because it uses native windows functions. Ifyou need cross platform IDE for C# develompment look at [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is Windows specific IDE. Supported operating systems (VS 2012) -

- Windows 7 SP1 (x86 and x64)
- Windows 8 (x86 and x64)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64)
- Windows Server 2012 (x64)

For more info, refer [Visual Studio Express 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web) page.